# Eclipse cdt couldn't resolve extern entities in c++ project

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

My problem with eclipse c++ project that eclipse could not resolve extern functions, namespaces, variables, etc...
Please, see the screenshot.

[image]

[Bigger one](http://imageshack.us/f/651/eclipse1e.jpg/)

So, for example jni type `jint` is not resolved by eclipse, but, as you can see `jni.h` is included and resolved (I can CNTRL+click on it and view its content), I've set up all needed include path, so all files are included as they supposed to, but eclipse doesn't resolve entities from them.

Where the problem might be there?

PS. I'm a newbbie in the c++ development with eclipse, so I might miss something, please help me, I'll appreciate it a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: The bigger version of the image doesn't appear to be any bigger and I can't read it so I wasn't able to tell exactly what library you were using. In my answer I just called it "JNI" Hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Tod, you need to click the loop to make it bigger.
The problem was resolved with manual reindex of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to tell Eclipse where you JNI library is.

If you've never done this, [see this wiki entry](http://wiki.embeddedethernet.com/Libraries#Linking). The section on linking has pictures and arrows and text that should walk you through the process.

Some general advice: Learn to distinguish between compiler errors and linker errors. If it's a compiler error, then you can look for missing include files etc. When it's a linker error it means it compiled and found all the headers just fine but when it went looking for the actual object to link to it couldn't find it. That typically means you have a library path issue to resolve.

One final warning, I have seen Eclipse change the toolchain settings all by itself, I [wrote this up in a blog entry](http://syncor.blogspot.com/2011/03/when-good-libraries-go-bad.html) if you want to see the one settings panel I now always avoid.

Answer (score 0):

This happens as krasilich said, when the linker faces an ambiguous variable and mess up in linking.

I fixed this problem temporarily when i faced it by re-edit the variable's header "the one includes the extern declaration", Clean and build again and the linker will be able to spot and link it in ease. But the permanent solution was by adding the workspace/folder path that includes the header file in C/C++ General>Paths and Symbols>Includes.

Possible explanation is a compiler and linker dependent. I tried to do that wit GCC without problems. When i use a private compiler like GHS this problem occurs with specific variables.